# Unable to select field list in Pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that has multiple pivot tables with data source in another workbook.

Some of them have the field list greyed out whether in the top "Analyze" ribbon or if I right click inside the pivot table.

[image: Analyze ribbon]]

[image: right click]

Comment: Is the file protected? Try the code first: Application.CommandBars("PivotTable Field List").Enabled = True ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True

Comment: I once had macro that protects sheets in the workbook. and ran it. But the state where you see the grey out is not protected